# Which ferry company offers online check-in from Tallin to Stockholm?

Tags: ferries, sea-travel, stockholm, tallinn

I will be travelling on this route in a couple of weeks, so I was wondering if there are any ferries that offer online check-in?

Comment: What is your reason for wanting online check-in? You will need to physically board the ferry before it leaves port anyway. Online check-in for _flights_ can help you avoid waiting in line at the airport behind passengers who are going on _different_ flights, but at a ferry terminal there's only that one ship, and they're not going to sail away while there's still a line of people waiting to have their tickets checked.

Answer (score 3):

> The [Stockholm Tallinn ferry route](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiU0P7i55XTAhVC44MKHSP6BOIQFgg1MAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.directferries.com.au%2Fstockholm_tallinn_ferry.htm&usg=AFQjCNG1HyhQw8ujSR_Np4T5Q8oIYG-Evg&sig2=ROS4R9V-DIM4V8gW_66w7w) connects Sweden with Estonia and is currently operated by 2 ferry companies. The Tallink Silja service runs up to 7 times per week with a sailing duration of around 15 hours 30 minutes while the St Peter Line service runs up to 1 times per week with a duration from 16 hr 30 min.

Neither line offers online checkin for that route.

[Tallink Siljia Line](http://www.tallink.com/)

While [Tallink does have online check-in](https://www.tallinksilja.com/good-to-know#16659110), it is only offered for Tallinn-Helsinki and Helsinki-Tallinn.

[St Peter Line](https://stpeterline.com/)

Does not appear to [have an online option](https://stpeterline.com/en/registracia-i-terminaly)

Answer (score 3):

*As a frequent traveller with Tallink Silja it's very easy for me to answer this question.*

---

## Cruises

You must get a physical paper key with a magnetic stripe for your cabin and to be able to pass the automatic gates at the terminal. You can get the key(s) either at the manned kiosks or using self-service machines.

There's no need to "check-in" before you get your key.

If you happen to loose your key you can ask the manned kiosks at the terminal or the reception (information) on the boat for a new one. You only have to show your ID and they're free of charge. Your old key will be instantly de-activated.

When leaving the ferry you can keep the key or throw it away - it's just paper.

## Regular

Tallink offers online check-in and mobile check-in foc some daytime routes where you normally don't have a cabin. These routes include Helsinki-Tallinn, Åland related trips via Turku, Stockholm or Helsinki (no cabin) and Vuosaari-Muuga.

---

I also suggest downloading the Tallink Silja app for your phone and to give it your booking details. It'll send you useful notifications and will also give you a QR code you can use at the self-service kiosks to get your tickets with one click.